# Visual C# - Web Browser check text on a page and if found do something

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I have Web Browser on my form. So here is the html:

```
<div class="life">Health:<span id="currenthp">4473</span>/<span id="maxhp">4473</span><div class="bar">
```

So I want to make an if else check - if for example **currenthp** is 2000 or less to do something. And how I can do this with a timer which will check every 3 minutes if **currenthp** is 2000 or less?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? This question doesn't really show much detail. Also, this will most likely require some JQuery for checking the values in the html, and a custom timer using System.Threading.Timer().

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask two things I'll answer in two parts:

Finding the value of `currenthp`:

```
public int findValue(String html) {
    // html being the HTML code currently in your browser
    int start = html.IndexOf("currenthp"); // find occurrence of 'currenthp' 
    start += "currenthp\">".Length; // update location to right after that id
    String newStr = arg.Substring(start); // take the substring from there
    int end = newStr.IndexOf("<"); // find the first occurrence of '<' (right after currenthp's value)
    int val = Int32.Parse(newStr.Substring(0, end)); // Extract the value
    return val;
}
```

That takes care of getting the value of `currenthp`. Now there's only the timer left. C# offers a terrific [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class for this.

Simply declare a new timer, set the callback function and interval, like this

```
System.Threading.Timer t;

public void setTimer() {
    // The first argument is the callback function, the function that is called on each tick.
    // Second: state object containing info for the callback
    // Third: Delay on the callback (in ms) after timer tick
    // Fourth: Time between ticks (in ms)
    t = new System.Threading.Timer(refreshCurrentHp, null, 0, 180000);
}
```

Now you only need to fill in `refreshCurrentHp` with your own function, and you are good to go.

Comment: Error 2 The name 'arg' does not exist in the current context 
I am getting this error on the findValue function ...
Also I will find the value with this function but how I can check if the value is 2000 or lower? Anyway, thanks for your fast reply! :)

Comment: The `arg` thing is my fault. that should be replaced by `html`. The function `findValue`returns what `currenthp` is at the moment. So now you just need to make another function to check if it's higher than 2000.